# Openshift error creating node.js latest cartridge

Tags: node.js, openshift

Openshift is failing to create the node.js application through the Openshift UI, using the node.js latest cartridge. It fails on create with the following error:

> Starting Node.js application...
>   The initial build for the application failed: Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 57eae88f7628e1677c000077 -c "exec
>   /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c4,c966' /bin/sh -c \"gear postreceive --init >> /tmp/initial-build.log
>   2>&1\""' returned an error. rc=255

And the tail of the log says:

> Preparing build for deployment
>
> Deployment id is b941b282
>
> Activating deployment
>
> Git Post-Receive Result: failure
>
> Activation status: failure
>
> Activation failed for the following gears:
>
> 57eae88f7628e1677c000077 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to 
>   execute: 'control start' for
>
> /var/lib/openshift/57eae88f7628e1677c000077/nodejs
>
> Deployment completed with status: failure
>
> post receive failed

I have no idea how to debug this. I've got a `package.json`, it has a "main" pointing to my `app.js`, and my `app.js` is using the environment variables to set the ip/port. It works locally with the usual `npm install && npm start`. This was a working app with the node 0.10 cartridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out, and I thought I'd provide the solution in case anyone else runs across it. So the node latest cartridge on the Openshift site is community provided, so it has some important differences from the normal node-0.10 cartridge. Three things in particular that I ran into:

1. It requires that your application expose a `GET /health` endpoint returning 200 OK, see: https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs/blob/master/usr/template/app.js#L14.
2. It uses different environment variables for ip and port, `NODE_IP` and `NODE_PORT`. I'm not sure if the normal open shift environment variables also work, because I never went back and tried it. But the example template at least uses the alternate environment variables. See https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs/blob/master/usr/template/app.js#L41.
3. It wants you to have a start script in your `package.json`, but also it's not actually running `npm start`, its emulating it. So some things that you'd expect to work with an `npm start` command don't work here. For example, I had my start command as `NODE_ENV=development node app.js` which is fine if run via `npm start` but not working at all when run through the custom control script, see https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs/blob/master/bin/control#L47.

Answer (score 0):

Node 6.6 versus 0.10 is a big difference.  You should get it working locally with the latest Node or whatever Node their new 'cartridge' is using.

Also look in that build.log

Comment: It does work with 6.6. How do I get the log for a container that never gets created?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to get a container started with just like the Node environment rather than running the node script itself and a shell like bash, zsh or fish and then remote in and start the node process yourself https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/ssh_environment.html